# Selector with changing Form IDs

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

i have a little Problem with Selection this Input form an the Submit Button within Casperjs.

```
<div id="id1d9" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="item wishname" id="id1da">
    <!-- <div class="item wishname">-->
    <label id="id1db" for="id1a0">
        E-Mail-Wunschname
    </label>

    <div class="input" id="id1a1">
        <input class="wishname feedback-panel-trigger multiReplaceCharsInWishnamelField" autocomplete="off" maxlength="40" value="" name="wishnamePanel:wishname:subForm:alias" id="id1a0" type="text">

            <span class="btn-positioner">
                <span class="btn-wrapper btn-m btn-key">
                    <input name="wishnamePanel:wishname:subForm:checkAvailability" id="checkAvailabilityBtn" value="Prüfen" type="submit">
                </span>
            </span>
```

The main Problem is, that the id's for the divs changes on every reload randomized. so casperjs like ==>

```
this.sendKeys('#id1a0 ',"Test String");
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the id always changes, you should use an alternate [selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) to target this element. You can use classes, tag names or combinations thereof.

What about this:

```
.wishname.feedback-panel-trigger.multiReplaceCharsInWishnamelField
```

or this:

```
.item.wishname > .input > input
```

If you have multiple items with the same classes you can try to iterate to get the right one.

Comment: @Chrisko Since this solved your issue, you might want to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) the answer. I've also noticed that you haven't accepted a whole lot of answer in your previous questions. If there were no good enough answers, then this is fine, but please check again if there are answers that you can accept.